# CRUD text using Regex - Ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, regex, ruby-on-rails-4, xml-parsing, string-parsing

I'm searching for a Solution to Parse and Update a Document. A very good example is user.js scripts.

Example Case:

A user uploads a `user.js` script to userscripts.org. The file **must have** a head of specific variables for the Browser. e.g.:

```
// ==UserScript==
// @name        Fancy Title
// @description Fancey Description
// @namespace   http://example.com
// @icon        http://example.com/icon.png
// @updateURL   http://example.com/user.js
// @downloadURL http://example.com/user.js
// @homepageURL http://example.com
// @require     https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js
// @include     http*://example.com
// @include     http://example.com/scripts/*
// @include     http://example.com/tags/*
// @grant       GM_getValue
// @grant       GM_setValue
// @grant       GM_listValues
// @version     1.0
// ==/UserScript==
```

What would be a good solution to back check those variables and `modify` or `add` them to the document. Basically importing the variables from `@testing.title` => `@name Fancy Title` and vice versa.

Let's say that if the `Meta Head` didn't contain the variables `@udpateURL` and `@downloadeURL`, I would add them respectively.

My first guess was to `regex` scan the document with `(@\w+)`, that will get me all the variables `@` but from there i'm lost :)

Can i solve this with plain ruby or is there handy gem available?

**Edit:**

*Sam* pointed out: `\/\/\s*@(\w+)\s+(.*)` Which captures exactly the variables i need..

The identifier(`@title`) and the value(`Fancy Title`).

How do i set, read or update them tho ?

---

@MrYoshiji provided me with a very awesome regex Meta Reader:

```
raw_metas = file_content.scan( /\A\/\/\s==UserScript==(\w|\W)*\/\/\s==\/UserScript==/ )
metas = {}
raw_metas.split(/\r\n|\n|\r/).each do |line_with_meta|
  attribute_name = line_with_data.scan(/@\w+/)
  value = line_with_data.sub("// #{attribute_name}", '').strip
  if metas[attribute_name.sub('@', '').to_sym].present?
    metas[attribute_name.sub('@', '').to_sym] = [ metas[attribute_name.sub('@', '').to_sym], value].flatten
  else
    metas[attribute_name.sub('@', '').to_sym] = value
  end
end
```

But i'm completely lost on how to set this up to interact with my Model's attributes.

---

**What Meta Data i need to Change**

Meaning that those attributes (:description etc) are stored in my Model and i need to pass them.

```
// @name => @model.name


// @description => @model.description
// @namespace   => Application root_path

// @updateURL   => @model show_view url
// @downloadURL => @Model show_view url
// @homepageURL => Application root_path

// @include     => Custom url (passed by me)
// @include     => Custom url (passed by me)
// @include     => Custom url (passed by me)

// @version     => @model.version
```

Comment: I don't know Ruby, but here is a more complete expression: [`\/\/\s*@(\w+)\s+(.*)`](http://www.rubular.com/r/3jlcNm27Lx)

Comment: Yup, sorry I can't help with Ruby..but maybe [this](http://www.regular-expressions.info/ruby.html) or [this](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.1/Regexp.html) can help.

Comment: I was just reading Regex Ruby Doc:) But having a hard time implementing. Thanx for the push tho.

Comment: FYI, added code to replace a token: in the example, `@version` is changed from `1.0` to `2.0`

Comment: Consider this: Keep the original file, parse it and construct a new file with the original file modified to fit your needs/requirements. You can have a class OriginalFile and another class Normalized file, where there is a one to one relation between the 2 classes. Normalized file would have a method to generate a JS file, and OriginalFile a method to return itself as a JS file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[EDIT: In a chat, you mentioned that your input may be on a single line. This [second demo](http://ideone.com/lqPHUE) shows a regex to deal with that, and also the general procedure to rebuild the string.]

This code stores the names and values in two hashes, replaces the `@version` with `2.0`, then outputs them (see the output at the bottom of the [online demo](http://ideone.com/YJaUSe)):

```
subject = <<-eos
@name        Fancy Title
// @description Fancey Description
// @namespace   http://example.com
// @icon        http://example.com/icon.png
// @updateURL   http://example.com/user.js
// @downloadURL http://example.com/user.js
// @homepageURL http://example.com
// @require     https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js
// @include     http*://example.com
// @include     http://example.com/scripts/*
// @include     http://example.com/tags/*
// @grant       GM_getValue
// @grant       GM_setValue
// @grant       GM_listValues
// @version     1.0
eos

regex = /\/\/ (@\w+)\s*([^\n]*)/

# put captures in two hashes
tokens = Hash.new
values = Hash.new
counter = 0
subject.scan(regex) {|m|
    tokens[counter] = $1
    values[counter] = $2
    counter += 1
}

# find hash key for @version
versionkey = tokens.index("@version")
# change version to 2.0
values[versionkey] = "2.0"

# print names and values
i=0
while i < counter  do
   puts "#{tokens[i]} : #{values[i]}"
   i +=1
end
```

The key is that token names are captured to Group 1, and token values are captured to Group 2 (see the regex explanation below). We build hashes with the values in these two groups.

To manipulate values, you have several options:

1. Use regex with `gsub` to replace lines in your string (not recommended)
2. Directly manipulate values in the hashes to your heart's content, as shown in the demo, where `@version` is changed to `2.0`, then rebuild the string if needed. That's what I would do.

**Explain Regex**

```
//                       # '// '
(                        # group and capture to \1:
  @                      #   '@'
  \w+                    #   word characters (a-z, A-Z, 0-9, _) (1 or
                         #   more times (matching the most amount
                         #   possible))
)                        # end of \1
\s*                      # whitespace (\n, \r, \t, \f, and " ") (0 or
                         # more times (matching the most amount
                         # possible))
(                        # group and capture to \2:
  [^\n]*                 #   any character except: '\n' (newline) (0
                         #   or more times (matching the most amount
                         #   possible))
)                        # end of \2
```

Comment: That is some Serious Code. Thank you first and foremost! SO from what i understand right now i have to create 2 model attributes: `:tokens` and `:values` right? If i misunderstood it, how do i take a string from my Model attribute and pass it in there? I'll update my question with that !

Comment: @TheMiniJohn Actually that's just a few lines of plain Ruby code, just what you asked. It's long because of the string. :) The two hashes are called `tokens` for the `@names` and `values` to hold the values. If you look at my example to modify the `@version`, you see that modifying the hashes is really easy. In the example we changed the @version value, but we can also change the name `@version` to `@VER` like this: `tokens[versionkey] = "@VER"` If you have any parameters in your code like `param` just say something like `values[somekey] = param`

Comment: @TheMiniJohn Hey, sorry I was away from the machine for a number of hours. The reason I didn't go with a single hash (for instance `token["@version"] = "1.0"` is that we would have collisions (you can only have one `@include` key). Not understanding what more do you need to store your values? They are already stored in the `tokens` and `values` hashes, and you can modify them at will.

Comment: Could you join me for 2 minutes ? :)